# YouTube resumable upload returning 500 Internal Server

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am currently having some 500 Internal Server error while uploading a video file to YouTube, I am sure my code is right ( as presented on google developers docs ) but this 500 Internal server error is driving me crazy ! I am wondering whether I am currently the only one having such issue , or anyone are too

```
<?php

    // Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
    set_include_path('google-api-php-client/src/');

    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
    session_start();

    /*
     * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
     * Google Developers Console <https://cloud.google.com/console>
     * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
     * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
     * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
     */
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'client_id';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

    // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    if ( $_GET['code'] ){
        if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state']) ) {
            die('The session state did not match.');
        }

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    }

    if ( $_SESSION['token'] ){
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

    }

    // Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        try{
        // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
            $videoPath = "video.flv";

        // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
        // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
        // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
        // video category.
            $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
            $snippet->setTitle("HELL");
            $snippet->setDescription("Hi");
            // $snippet->setTags(array("", ""));

        // Numeric video category. See
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
            // $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
        // "private" and "unlisted".
            $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
            $status->privacyStatus = "public";

        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
            $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
            $video->setSnippet($snippet);
            $video->setStatus($status);

        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
            $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
            $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $client,
                $insertRequest,
                'video/*',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
                );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
                $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
                $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
            }

            fclose($handle);

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
            $client->setDefer(false);

            $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
                $status['snippet']['title'],
                $status['id']);

            $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

        } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        }

        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
        $state = mt_rand();
        $client->setState($state);
        $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        $htmlBody ='<h3>Authorization Required</h3><p>You need to <a href="'.$authUrl.'">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>';
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Uploaded</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?=$htmlBody?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you try a small mp4 video? It could be because of video type or length.

Comment: It might be ! I am trying with an flv file :p my bad ! it's very small though